# Plot just one country using matplotlib.basemap and arcgisimage

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot a map of a country with precipitation data and a satelite image in the background. I made a mask for the data, so the precipitation is show correctly. But I'm having problems to apply the same mask to the satelite image. Here is my code:

```
gdf = geopandas.read_file('shapes/brazil_shape')
mask = shapely.vectorized.contains(gdf.dissolve().geometry.item(), lons, lats)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})
fig.set_size_inches(15, 10, forward=True)
   
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=extent_values[0], llcrnrlat=extent_values[1], urcrnrlon=extent_values[2], urcrnrlat=extent_values[3], epsg=4326, ax=ax)
m.arcgisimage(service='World_Imagery', xpixels=1000, dpi=300, verbose=False)
   
x, y = m(lons, lats)
cs = m.contourf(x, y, np.where(mask, values, np.nan), levels=levels, cmap=precip_colormap, norm=norm, alpha=0.7, extend='max')
```

I've tried put "mask = mask" in the m.arcgisimage() function, but nothing happens.